# Asp.net session termination

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I kill session and go back again through it's url it shows my username.
I have tried `session.abandon()`,`session.RemoveAll()`,`session.Clear()`....
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Hey Guys Thanks.
But When I go through browser back button the code works fine but dosent when pasting URL manually.Here is the code

```
public partial class products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["full_name"] == null)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Your are Logged out.Please sign In to Continue.');location='Log-In.aspx'</script>");   
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("hi "+Session["full_name"].ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Remove("full_name");
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> alert('logged out successfully');location='Log-In.aspx'</script>");
    }
}
```

Hopefully It will help

Comment: Do you go back using browser back button?

Comment: Can you update the question with your log in code?

Comment: Adil is right...Problem is with the browser's history...It's taking you the previous visited page only.

Comment: if your page having master page, then on master page check the session , if it is null redirect to login page, and aslo try to manually assign null to session after abandon

Answer (score 2):

Do you wan't to log out the user? In that case killing of the session won't work for you.
If you use Forms Authentication, you can execute `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your page's `Load` event from where you're logging out.

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

And call any of the above methods mentioned in your question to kill session.

Comment: Not one of those methods kills the session.

Comment: @Alexander Of course these methods are not for killing sessions. i've suggested him for expiring back button browser functionality...After using this snippet he can call any of method to terminate session..

Comment: I'm afraid these functions won't do any good for the back button browser functionality. This might become a religious question, but it is my opinion that a web application must support the back button. Because it's there.

Comment: This will expire and flush the previous page from browser's cache...and will show page expired error after clicking on back button...and it must be there in some cases...

Comment: These methods concern the ASP.NET Cache, not the browser's cache. [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Correct..And Asp.Net Cache takes data from the originating server to the requesting browser and stores it on browser side...please read it on [ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)and if we clear the cache it will clear it from browser as well. Try that code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Hope the problem will be solve

```
//old authentication, kill it
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
//or use Response.Redirect to go to a different page
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage("Session=Expired");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```